# How to bypass gatekeeper on macOS Catalina for only one particular program?

Tags: macos-catalina, osx-gatekeeper, sqlitestudio

I don't want to find some disabling of gatekeeper where I just turn it off completely. 
However, I use SQLiteStudio probably more often than majority of the applications on my computer, but every single time I open it (which I try to avoid and just keep it open constantly) it requires that I go into Security & Privacy and hit "Open Anyways" to force it to open since it's apparently from an unidentified developer... 
Anyways, I'm hoping there's some fix or something I can do to permanently disable the warning for this particular application only?
Most other applications when I download them and open them and they have that issue it only occurs the single first time I open it - and then when I hit "Open Anyways" it disables the warning from then on. But this application is the exception and I'm really hoping for a solution. Any help???